# How to prevent text to overlap the image?

Tags: html, css

Text is overlapping the image. 
This is screenshot of overlapped contents:
[image]

CSS class of text:

```
._text
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    margin-left:30px;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#FF0000;
    z-index:1;
}
```

CSS class of image:

```
._images
{
    position:absolute;
    float:right;
    margin-top:18px;
    margin-left:165px;
    width:170px;
    height:170px;
    z-index:0;
}
```

Give me some solution to move the text away from the image.

Thank you in advance.

**Edition**

Here is HTML (as demanded in comments) dynamically returned by ajax:

```
<div id="rNo">(12 / 14)</div>
    <img class="_images" src="Buildings_files/school2.png" align="right">
    <h4 class="building_heading">School</h4>
    <span id="m_text_area_body">School is .... <br><br></span>
    <span class="_text">» Upgrade Governor Palace to (level-10) to construct this building. You have suffecient golds to construct it</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `padding-right` to the `._text` container.

Comment: `position:absolute; float:right;` Is your problem. You can't mix both. Remove the `position: absolute`. You can also remove the `float: left` on the text

Comment: You shouldn't have to give a fixed width, padding, or overflow hidden. As @Brewal mentioned, the problem is the absolute position of the image div.

Comment: You should also include the HTML in your question, not just the CSS. Also, a link to a working example is also good in these instances, maybe a fiddle of some sort

Comment: Rashid, include your HTML as well.

Comment: I have included HTML in edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add padding to the right like this

```
 ._text{padding-right: 170px;}
```

Or set width of your text like this

```
._text{width: /*distance between left of text and image*/;}
```

And you can also try giving both the text and the image the same z-index like this

```
 ._text{z-index:1;}  ._images{z-index:1;}
```

Comment: I don't like your first two suggestions because I shouldn't have to give a fixed width, padding, or overflow hidden. 
And last suggestion of giving same z-indexes to both (text and image) is also not working.